# Change property or state in store "1" from action in store "2"

Tags: javascript, notifications, store, inject, mobx

Is it possible to change the state of some store from the action of a different store. I usually use Inject on all components but i guess they don't work for the stores.

I have a dedicated store which controls the state of notification popup. It would be great to change it's open/close state and the message from the actions of all other stores in which I execute ajax calls.

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be easiest just to import your notification store to the other stores and call some action that way:

```
// notificationStore.js
class NotificationStore {
  @observable notif = { state: 'closed', msg: '' };
  @action changeState(state, msg) {
    this.notif.state = state;
    this.notif.msg = msg;
  }
}

export default new NotificationStore();

// otherStore.js
import notificationStore from './notificationStore.js'

class OtherStore {
  @action someAction(someData) {
    // Some code...
    notificationStore.changeState('open', 'someAction complete');
  }
}
```